# Permutar un vector cuatro veces con restricciones utilizando R

Tags: array, r, funciones, matemáticas, rstudio

Tengo el siguiente vector :

```
FirstName <- c(11, 10, 4, 7, 1, 13, 14, 9, 8, 12, 5, 2, 6, 3)
```

Quiero obtener 4 vectores más, de tal forma que en la posición `i-ésima` no se repita el mismo número que en el vector `FirstName` y que tampoco se repitan entre los `4` vectores resultantes. Necesariamente cada vector tiene que contener todos los números sólo una vez.

Además, deseo añadir una restricción:
En la posición `i-ésima` de todos lo vectores, respecto a ellos y el vector `FirstName` sólo contenga, por ejemplo, el número 14 y no el 13 o a la inversa.

Aquí adjunto mi código :

```
sam_minusone <- function(v, z) {
   t <- sample(v[v != z],1)
   return(t)
}

v = FirstName 
t = c()

for(i in 2:length(v)){
    z <- FirstName[i-1]
    number <- sam_minusone(v,z)
    t <- c(t,number)
    v <- setdiff(v,number)
}
t
```

Aunque el vector `t` posee una componente menos respecto al vector `FirstName`.

Gracias por la ayuda y por vuestro tiempo.

Comment: Bienvenido @oriol a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, favoreciendo tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Hola Oriol, modifica tu pregunta, agrega por favor lo que has tratado e investigado, revisa el documento que comparte Hubert , [ask], saludos.

Comment: Disculpa @Elenasys♦. He adjuntado un pequeño código.

Comment: @Oriol No debes pedir disculpas, al contrario te agradecemos modificáras tu pregunta, de esta forma puedes encontrar buenas respuestas y tu pregunta puede ser de ayuda a otros usuarios del sitio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realmente la función `sample` es de gran ayuda para mezclar o extraer datos sin reposición -o con reposición-, pero **usarse desde un inicio** en este caso concreto, creo que se estaría entrando a una **empresa sin muchas garantías de éxito**, es decir, el camino sería más largo.

La pregunta a mi entender, parece ser una variante de [sudoku](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmos_para_la_resoluci%C3%B3n_de_sudokus), con la salvedad que sólo las filas deben sumar lo mismo `sum(1:14)==105 #TRUE`

Una forma de evitar que los números pertenecientes a la misma columna se repitan, es generar un desfase de posición entre las filas de por lo menos una unidad *-esto más adelante se le llamará `factD: factor de desfase`-* y que los valores de dichas filas (vectores) sean cíclicas como un reloj.

Al hablar de **ciclos** existe una herramienta llamada [aritmética modular](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aritm%C3%A9tica_modular). En **R** dicha herramienta se le usa mediante el operador `%%`, véase lo siguiente con un desfase de una unidad entre filas:

```
1:14%%14
2:15%%14
3:16%%14
4:17%%14

 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13  0
 [1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13  0  1
 [1]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13  0  1  2
 [1]  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13  0  1  2  3

for (j in 5:8) print (((j):(j+13))%%14)
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13  0  1  2  3  4
 [1]  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13  0  1  2  3  4  5
 [1]  7  8  9 10 11 12 13  0  1  2  3  4  5  6
 [1]  8  9 10 11 12 13  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
```

Nótese que las columnas no se repiten (son cíclicas), aquí está la clave, porque las filas siempre sumaran `105` como el **sudoku**, *-el cero (`0`) es un detalle menor, puede cambiarse por 14 luego-*.

Entonces generándase los "datos de partida o inicio":

```
set.seed(20190320) # una semilla para replicar las pruebas
m <- matrix(0, nrow=4, ncol=14)
desf <- sample(0:13,1) # esto viene
factD<-2 # cuando es uno (1), se tiene lo expuesto al inicio
         # ajustar de acuerdo a lo que se necesita
         # no he probado todo el intervalo [1,13]
for (j in 1:4) {
    d<-((j*factD+desf):(j*factD+desf+13))%%14
    d[d %in% 0]<-14
    m[j,]<-d
}
m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14]
[1,]   13   14    1    2    3    4    5    6    7     8     9    10    11    12
[2,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10    11    12    13    14
[3,]    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11    12    13    14     1     2
[4,]    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13    14     1     2     3     4
```

> Nótese que el desfase entre los elementos de las filas es `2`, asimismo el ciclo (`desf`) corresponde a `11` porque la `celda[1,1]` es `13`... `11+2`, es decir si se continuase con el ejemplo inicial (`8:21%%14`)... `11:24%%14` esta expresión luego de sumarle el `factD=2`, sería `13:26%%14`, correspondiente a la primera fila de la matriz **m**.

Lo que viene a continuación es mezclar los datos sin que se pierda la integrar alcanzada en el paso previo.

```
# se mezcla, se baraja, se permutan o se extrae sin reposición
# las posiciones de las columnas y las filas
shuffleCol <- sample(1:14, 14, replace = FALSE) 
shuffleRow <- sample(1:4 ,4, replace = FALSE)

shuffleCol   #  [1] 4 6 11 13  2  9 14  8 12  5  7  3 10  1
shuffleRow   #  [1] 2 4 1 3
```

Luego se crea una matriz que contendrá los resultados de acuerdo a los indices (filas y columnas) previamente generados de forma aleatoria.

```
mf<-matrix(0 ,nrow=4, ncol=14)
# se insertan las filas en este orden:
#     mf       m
# 2 4 1 3 <- 1 2 3 4
mf[shuffleRow,] <- m[1:4,]
mf
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14]
[1,]    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11    12    13    14     1     2
[2,]   13   14    1    2    3    4    5    6    7     8     9    10    11    12
[3,]    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13    14     1     2     3     4
[4,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10    11    12    13    14

# lo mismo con las columnas pero solo con la matriz mf
# mf: 4 6 11 13 2 9 14 8 12 5  7  3  10 1
# mf: 1 2 3  4  5 6 7  8 9  10 11 12 13 14
mf[,1:14]<-mf[,shuffleCol]
mf
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14]
[1,]    6    8   13    1    4   11    2   10   14     7     9     5    12     3
[2,]    2    4    9   11   14    7   12    6   10     3     5     1     8    13
[3,]    8   10    1    3    6   13    4   12    2     9    11     7    14     5
[4,]    4    6   11   13    2    9   14    8   12     5     7     3    10     1
```

Finalmente quería añadir que el factor de desfase (`factD`) se ajustó a dos (`2`) en este caso, para allanar un poco la explicación de lo resuelto, no obstante también puede ser aleatorio `factD<-sample(1:Tope,1)` podría ser incluso hasta trece (`13`) *-o el rango empezarlo desde 2, 3,...-*, honestamente no he realizado las pruebas hasta ese número (`13`), sería cuestión que lo definan (`Tope`) de acuerdo a sus necesidades.

> En todo caso, no perder de vista que debe existir siempre un desfase de al menos una unidad entre las valores de las filas que serán columnas, porque también se está agregando la variable `desf`.

### Ampliación Respuesta

Una forma de verificar el comportamiento que tendrán los datos iniciales, es mediante la evaluación de las combinaciones que son generadas con las variables `desf`, `factD`, para este caso, los bucles `for`, ayudarían a tal fin:

```
for (desf in 0:13){
    for (factD in 1:13){
        print('------------------------------------------')
        print(paste("desf:",desf,"factD:",factD))
        print('------------------------------------------')
        for (j in 1:4) {
            d<-((j*factD+desf):(j*factD+desf+13))%%14
            d[d %in% 0]<-14
            print(d)
        }
        cat("\n")
    }
}
```

Comment: Una aportación de gran ayuda @Hubert Ronald ! Sólo comentar que, al ver todas las posibles combinaciones, para todo `desf` los valores `factD` no pueden ser los siguientes : 1, 5, 7, 9 ,13. Ya que si no es así no se cumple la restricción final propuesta en el enunciado. Un saludo!